# Love2D Animation Error

Tags: animation, lua, love2d

I am having an annoying bug with my character movement animations. That bug is, that whenever I run the code, the animation only works for the 'W' key. (The movement is WASD.) I don't get any compilation errors and I am using Love2D 0.10.1

Here is the movement handler function

```
   function player.move(dt)
       if love.keyboard.isDown("d") and
       player.xvel < player.speed then
          player.xvel = player.xvel + player.speed * dt
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/walk1.png")
       else
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/static.png")
       end

       if love.keyboard.isDown("a") and
       player.xvel > -player.speed then
          player.xvel = player.xvel - player.speed * dt
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/walk1.png")
       else
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/static.png")
       end

       if love.keyboard.isDown("s") and
       player.yvel < player.speed then
          player.yvel = player.yvel + player.speed * dt
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/walk1.png")
       else
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/static.png")
       end

       if love.keyboard.isDown("w") and
       player.yvel > -player.speed then
          player.yvel = player.yvel - player.speed * dt
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/walk1.png")
       else
          player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/static.png")
       end

    end
```

Anything helps! Oh, and also, if anyone knows how to make it to where it goes to a certain frame every x amount of seconds, that's be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I could propose for the problem with animation would be to use `if` only at the key `d`, and `elseif` on the other cases. The problem is caused by the fact that if any other key is pressed, but `w` isn't, then the

```
if love.keyboard.isDown("w") and
player.yvel > -player.speed then
    player.yvel = player.yvel - player.speed * dt
    player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/walk1.png")
else
    player.image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/static.png")
end
```

switch enters the `else` part, because `w` is not down, and in the else part it sets the image to `static.png`.

Here you can read about the `if-elseif-else-end` control structure of Lua:
http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/if_else_statement_in_lua.htm

Be careful with the fact that some languages use it as `else if`, but in Lua there is no space between, so it is written like `elseif`.